# Return Iterator of an array wrapped in an Option

Tags: arrays, rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to return an array iterator of an array in an `Option` from the closure passed to a `filter_map` so I can flatten it afterwards.
Unfortunately, `rustc` produces the following error:

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `res`

returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
main.rs(3, 5): returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
main.rs(3, 10): `res` is borrowed here
```

for the minimal example:

```rust
fn demo<'a>() -> Option<impl Iterator + 'a> {
    let res = [1,2];
    Some(res.into_iter())
}
```

Though the complete code I'm trying to make work is this:

```rust
fn generate_next<'a>(prev: &'a [u32]) -> impl Iterator + 'a {

    let mut counter = 1_u32;

    prev.windows(2).filter_map(move |window| {
        
        if window[0] == window[1] {
            counter+=1;
            None
        } else {
            let res = [counter, window[0]];
            counter=1;
            Some(res.into_iter())
        }
    }).flatten()
}
```

Both produce the same error for the `Some(...)` part.

If I understand correctly, the code should work, because the `into_iter()` method consumes the array and produces an iterator from it. `Some` should then take ownership of the iterator via a move. Why does rustc think that I'm borrowing `res` here?

I'm also open to other ways to implement the `generate_next` function.

Comment: What are you expecting that `'a` lifetime to achieve in the shorter example?

Comment: It was required for the error to be same, removing those lifetime parameters produced a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [`into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.into_iter) on an array produces the same result as calling [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), i.e. an iterator over references. This is an unfortunate gotcha within the Rust standard library.

You can accomplish what you want by using [`std::iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html) to create iterators of `counter` and `window[0]` and then [`chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) them together:

```rust
fn generate_next<'a>(prev: &'a [u32]) -> impl Iterator + 'a {
    let mut counter = 1_u32;

    prev.windows(2)
        .filter_map(move |window| {
            if window[0] == window[1] {
                counter += 1;
                None
            } else {
                let counter_iter = std::iter::once(counter);
                let window_iter = std::iter::once(window[0]);
                counter = 1;
                Some(counter_iter.chain(window_iter))
            }
        })
        .flatten()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee2c22910763d4e9ae37e3f378f820ab)

Comment: Probably should check for dupes before answering. There's at least one of these every week.

Comment: Seems like there still are a couple of bugs in my implementation so I can't confirm whether it actually works right now, but it seems like a possible solution.